# LoadImage() with QRCode bitmap failing unless file is opened/saved with MS Paint first

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, qr-code

I am trying to read a bmp file using  below function in c++

```
HANDLE hBmp = LoadImage(0, L"C:\\Users\\abhinay\\Desktop\\Sample.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,    LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

In my scenario the sample.bmp is a QRCode which is generated by a 3rd part QRCode library. When i try to read QRCode generated with above "LoadImage" function i get hBmp as "NULL".

I opened QRCode image "sample.bmp" with MS paint and saved it as .bmp in 24-bit Bitmap and now i am able to load the file using the same "LoadImage" function above.

Can you please help why the bmp file was not loaded in the first case and how can i make the the generated QRCode image to be loaded properly loaded using "LoadImage" function without the need of converting into 24-bit Bitmap image using MS Paint. Also let me know if its easy to print a .jpg or .png image instead of a .bmp file.

Thanks
Abhinay

**Edit**
I have tried using "GetLastError()" as mentioned below

```
HANDLE hBmp = LoadImage(NULL, bmpfile, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

if (hBmp == NULL)
{
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    if (dw == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "get last error is null", "ABHINAY", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "get last error is not null", "ABHINAY", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST);
    }

}
```

And i get the error message "get last error is null".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx: "If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError"

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the "GetLastError" function but still i dont get any debug information. If i open the same file and save as 24-bmp format in MS paint the image then loads. I think the image generated is not compatible initially. I think i am missing some thing silly but i m unable to find what i am missing. This is the first i m wrkng on images.

Comment: If you open up the original bit map with a text editor such as WordPad or NotePad what are the first two characters of the file?  Windows bitmap files normally have BM as the first two characters in the file.

Comment: @AbhilashAruva what value did GetLastError return?

Comment: @RichardChambers The first characters of the original bit map file are _"BMöJ     6   (   ¨   Xÿÿÿ     "_. The first characters of the converted bitmap file using MS paint is _"BMöJ     6   (   ¨   ¨   "_.

Comment: @brightstar GetLastError returned NULL.

Comment: if GetLastError  returns NULL (or 0) which means no error, while LoadImage returns NULL, then you probably have found a bug in WinAPI function.

Comment: check for external problems that might cause such error, ie. if your code leaks handles then there might be non free left causing such error, althought it looks more like your image is unreadable to LoadImage.

Comment: The BMP file format is fairly complex. If you can load a bitmap produced by MS Paint, but cannot load the original bitmap, chances are, that the 3rd party tool produced an invalid BMP file. MS Paint does a lot to cover up for invalid files on load, and does produce compliant BMP files on save.

Comment: Yeah even i feel the same. MS paint is converting the incompatible bmp image to compatible bmp image. Is there any function which converts any bmp file to a compatible format which can be loaded LoadImage function.

Comment: You might have better luck using the [Windows Imaging Component (WIC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) to load the image. I don't know how much error resilience - if any - it incorporates, though. To diagnose the issue, you could also load the file as is and inspect the header information for possible errors. This, however, is somewhat tedious and requires intimate knowledge of the [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am pretty new to these images in c++. I have found a workaround to fix this issue. I am generating the image in JPEG format from my library and then converting this image into bmp format using gdi+. The loadImage function is now able to load the new bmp image. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: JPEG compression is **lossy**. Images with sharp transitions between adjacent pixels (like QR code images) will exhibit very visible image quality degradation at every transition between black and white pixels. If you want to use your workaround, consider using the **lossless** PNG image format instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please help why the bmp file was not loaded in the first case?

There are lots of variations of BMP format.  It's quite possible that the original image was in a variant that LoadImage cannot directly convert to a DIB.  So you converted it in Paint to a BMP variant that it could open.

In particular, there are variants where raw PNG of JPG data can be packed into a BMP container.  This is typically used to pass the compressed image data directly to a printer that can decompress itself.  (In my experience, only a few printers actually support this.)  I don't think the GDI API can actually do much else with BMPs of this type.  Paint, on the other hand, has codecs for PNG and JPG, so I'd expect its repertoire might include those formats, even when they're packed in a BMP header.

> how can i make the the generated QRCode image to be loaded properly loaded using "LoadImage" function without the need of converting into 24-bit Bitmap image using MS Paint.

I don't think you'll be able to do it with LoadImage without converting the file.  Modern versions of Windows have other APIs that can load BMPs (and PNG and JPG), so you might try one of these.

- [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533830(v=vs.85).aspx) (probably the simplest)
- [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719877(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [OLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693724(v=vs.85).aspx)  (probably the most complex, especially if you're not used to COM)

> Also let me know if its easy to print a .jpg or .png image instead of a .bmp file.

If you use one of the APIs I listed to load the image, printing it should be pretty straightforward.