# C++ - Problem with create bmp file and show it by createwindow()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap

I have a function that get data and create .BMP file as Qr Code.

```
    int CreateBmpFile(std::wstring barcode)
{
    const std::string data(barcode.begin(), barcode.end());
    //const char* data;
    char* szSourceSring = (char*)data.c_str();
    unsigned int    unWidth, x, y, l, n, unWidthAdjusted, unDataBytes;
    unsigned char* pRGBData, * pSourceData, * pDestData;
    QRcode* pQRC;
    FILE* f;

    // Compute QRCode

    if (pQRC = QRcode_encodeString(szSourceSring, 0, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8, 1))
        //if(pQRC=QRcode_encodeString8bit(szSourceSring,0,QR_ECLEVEL_L))
    {
        unWidth = pQRC->width;
        unWidthAdjusted = unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER * 3;
        if (unWidthAdjusted % 4)
            unWidthAdjusted = (unWidthAdjusted / 4 + 1) * 4;
        unDataBytes = unWidthAdjusted * unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;

        // Allocate pixels buffer

        if (!(pRGBData = (unsigned char*)malloc(unDataBytes)))
        {
            printf("Out of memory");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Preset to white

        memset(pRGBData, 0xff, unDataBytes);


        // Prepare bmp headers

        BITMAPFILEHEADER kFileHeader;
        kFileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42;  // "BM"
        kFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + unDataBytes;
        kFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
        kFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
        kFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) +          sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        BITMAPINFOHEADER kInfoHeader;
        kInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        kInfoHeader.biWidth = unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
        kInfoHeader.biHeight = -((int)unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER);
        kInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        kInfoHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        kInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        kInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;


        // Convert QrCode bits to bmp pixels

        pSourceData = pQRC->data;
        for (y = 0; y < unWidth; y++)
        {
            pDestData = pRGBData + unWidthAdjusted * y * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
            for (x = 0; x < unWidth; x++)
            {
                if (*pSourceData & 1)
                {
                    for (l = 0; l < OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER; l++)
                    {
                        for (n = 0; n < OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER; n++)
                        {
                            *(pDestData + n * 3 + unWidthAdjusted * l) = PIXEL_COLOR_B;
                            *(pDestData + 1 + n * 3 + unWidthAdjusted * l) = PIXEL_COLOR_G;
                            *(pDestData + 2 + n * 3 + unWidthAdjusted * l) = PIXEL_COLOR_R;
                        }
                    }
                }
                pDestData += 3 * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
                pSourceData++;
            }
        }


        // Output the bmp file

        if (!(fopen_s(&f, OUT_FILE, "wb")))
        {
            fwrite(&kFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f);
            fwrite(&kInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, f);
            fwrite(pRGBData, sizeof(unsigned char), unDataBytes, f);

            fclose(f);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unable to open file");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Free data

        free(pRGBData);
        QRcode_free(pQRC);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NULL returned");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After call this function, my bmp file create and I can open it in windows to show.

If I want to load it and show in my win32 dialog by follow code:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"samanqrcode.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_SHARED);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    WCHAR szTest[10]; 
    swprintf_s(szTest, 10, L"%d", err);
    if(hBitmap == NULL)
        ::MessageBox(_hWnd, szTest, L"rrrrrrr", 0);


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        _Image_Barcode = ::CreateWindow(_T("STATIC"), _T(""),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP,
            85, 70, 230, 230,
            _hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDI_BARCODE_IMAGE,
            _hinst,
            NULL);
        if (_Image_Barcode == NULL)
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
    }

    ::SendMessage(_Image_Barcode, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
```

LoadImage function return NULL and error code is 0.

If I use other file name (any bmp file for example created by paint application in windows or other...) in LoadImage function, bmp file show correctly.

Is my method to create bmp file incorrect?

Edit:

This question is like my problem.
[LoadImage() with QRCode bitmap failing unless file is opened/saved with MS Paint first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26159489/3477587)

That user in comment say: @AbhilashAruva
Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am pretty new to these images in c++. I have found a workaround to fix this issue. I am generating the image in JPEG format from my library and then converting this image into bmp format using gdi+. The loadImage function is now able to load the new bmp image. Thanks for all the help. – Abhilash Aruva Oct 8 '14 at 7:40

What is he mine? I can not implement his method.

Comment: First thing I would try is to view your bitmap in a bitmap editting tool (such as Paint). If it can't view your bitmap then you know there's something wrong with it.

Comment: @john: *my bmp file create and I can open it in windows to show* seems to indicate the poster has already done that, doesn't it?

Comment: I open this file in paint and windows viewer successfully.

Comment: OK, well clearly the file is correct. Apologies for not reading more carefully. Most common reason for LoadImage failing is that the program is looking for the file in a different place from where the programmer has placed the file.

Comment: @john: If LoadImage function can not find file or path file, return error 2. If I have change file name  this return error.

Comment: From the documentation `Do not use LR_SHARED for images that have non-standard sizes, that may change after loading, or that are loaded from a file.`

Comment: Also `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` is irrelevant for a bitmap.

Comment: IF I use only LR_LOADFROMFILE for flag, so I have my problem yet. It test it with any flag.

Comment: Where are you saving the bitmap file? Have you tried passing LoadImage a fully-qualified file name (C:\Whatever\samanqrcode.bmp) instead of just the filename?

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, I try any.

Comment: I read this documentation. Can this help me?!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/storing-an-image

Comment: The [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec) natively provides a [BMP encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec#native-codecs). Use that if you want to be sure to produce valid BMP files.

Comment: I find solution. Using from gdi+ to convert bmp to jpg and convert jpg to bmp.

Comment: Converting a bitmap image to a JPEG image *always* loses image information. It's lossy. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, dropping information is likely not part of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution. Using from gdi+ to convert bmp to jpg and convert jpg to bmp.